# dojox.grid.DataGrid dojox.data.HtmlStore

Tags: grid, dojo

It would be so slick if you could use dojox.grid.DataGrid and dojox.data.HtmlStore together.  Maybe there is an easier way to get sortable tables with Dojo, but this is all I can come up with... and it doesn't quite work.  There is a DojoCampus example of this but it does not work either!  What am I missing?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
 @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.3/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
 @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.3/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css";
 @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.3/dojox/grid/resources/tundraGrid.css";
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var djConfig = {parseOnLoad: true};
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.3/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojox.data.HtmlStore");
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid"); 
 dojo.require('dojo.parser');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var layoutBooks = [[{
        field: "isbn",
        name: "ISBN",
        width: 10
    },
    {
        field: "author",
        name: "Author",
        width: 10
    },
    {
        field: "title",
        name: "Title",
        width: 'auto'
    }]];
</script>

</head>
<body class=tundra>

<b>
    Standard HTML table:
</b>
<br>
<table id="myData2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                isbn
            </th>
            <th>
                title
            </th>
            <th>
                author
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                A9B57C
            </td>
            <td>
                Title of 1
            </td>
            <td>
                Author of 1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                A9B57F
            </td>
            <td>
                Title of 2
            </td>
            <td>
                Author of 2
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                A9B577
            </td>
            <td>
                Title of 3
            </td>
            <td>
                Author of 3
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                A9B574
            </td>
            <td>
                Title of 4
            </td>
            <td>
                Author of 4
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                A9B5CC
            </td>
            <td>
                Title of 5
            </td>
            <td>
                Author of 5
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<b>
    dojox.grid.DataGrid connected to the above table:
</b>
<br>
<div dojoType="dojox.data.HtmlStore" dataId="myData2" jsId="gridStore">
</div>
<div style="width: 400px; height: 200px;">
    <div id="grid" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" store="gridStore" structure="layoutBooks"
    query="{}" rowsPerPage="40">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this example doesn't work because of line breaks in your th tags. Try writing ths in one line:

```
<th>isbn</th>
```

Comment: Yup. That was it. Thanks Ivan!

Answer (score 0):

for sorting the grid you can do grid.setSortIndex(colIndx,isAsc)

1) colIndx is zero based index of the columns of the grid.

2) if isAsc is true that column will be sorted in ascending order.